# How to get the same instance of a class in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, 2d-games

Good morning,

I have one little problem.
I created one class named Map(). In this class there in one method that generate an Array. Then i created other two classes (Top and Bottom) that extend Map. Then I created 2 objects. One of Top and one of Bottom. I want to get the same array for the Top's object and for the Bottom's object. Here is the code Source:

```
public class Map{
    public Map(){}

    public int [] yTopValues()
    {
        int [] arrayTopY = new int[100];
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            arrayTopY[i]=randomInt(-50,50);//it puts in i-th position an int between 50 and -50
        return arrayTopY;
    }

    public int [] yBottomValues()
    {
        int [] arrayBottomY = yTopValues;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            arrayBottomY[i]=arrayBottomY[i]-250;
        return arrayBottomY;
    }

    public int [] xValues()
    {
        int [] arrayX = new int[100];
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
            arrayX[i]=randomInt(0,50);//it puts in i-th position an int between 0 and 50
        return arrayX;
    }
//other stuff
}


public class TopMap extends Map{

    public TopMap(){
        this.area=new Area(new Polygon(
            this.xValues,
            this.yTopValues,
            200)            
    );
    }

public class BottomMap extends Map{

    public BottomMap(){
        this.area=new Area(new Polygon(
            this.xValues,
            this.yBottomValues,
            200)            
    );
    }
```

In the View class I created two objects one of TopMap and one of BottomMap then I drew the areas with *g2.draw(topMap.area)* and *g2.draw(bottomMap.area)*

I need the 2 polygons to be similar, but both of them are different because the method is executed twice. What should I do?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Design makes no sense.  Why would Map create top and bottom values rather than let the subclasses create their own?

Comment: Since `Map` doesn't store the arrays, every call to any of the three methods will create a new array, even if called on the same instance of `Map`. The only way to get the same array repeatedly, would be to store it somewhere. Perhaps by not subclassing `Map`, but instead have both `TopMap` and `BottomMap` take a `Map` instance, and have that `Map` instance store the arrays in fields.

Comment: I wat to create a tunnel that is not linear... and yes it might not makes any sense.. I am not a professional programmer. I just need it for a project

Answer (score 0):

The class Map does not hold the array. It is local only to the xValues() method. If you want the other classes to get that exact array do this:

```
/*
 * Since this is a variable in the CLASS field, this object will
 * be accessible to the child class.
 */
private int[] arrayX = new int[100];

public Map(){
     createArrayX(); // This makes sure that the array is created, or else
     // every value inside of it will be 0.
}

public void createArrayX(){ // Exact same thing as xValues(), but without the return type
     for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        arrayX[i]=randomInt(0,50);
     }
}

public int[] getArrayX(){ // The method that gets the array.
     return arrayX;
}
```